# Chrome Adware Infected Across Windows and OSX

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware, malware-removal, adware

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I have some adware infecting Chrome and it started at the same time on both my Windows 10 machine and my Mac.  Basically, a few times a day, a full screen popup will appear that says "Sponsored by...[the name of the current website]" with grid of off-putting ads.

I've checked extensions and there isn't one for this, and I've run multiple adware scanning programs on both computers, but it just won't go away.

Any information on adware synching across Chrome on different machines?

Thanks!

[Image of popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHP6j.jpg)

Comment: By full screen pop-ups, do you mean it takes over the page? If so it might be your ISP or a extension. How did you eliminate all the extensions?

Comment: I updated the description with an image of the popup.

Answer (score 0):

At least for me, this was caused by the "HTTP Headers" extension. Apparently it was purchased/taken over and then was updated to serve adware. Since Chrome automatically syncs extensions, it happens on any machine where you use that profile.